# Include subdirectory as part of Jekyll's post URL

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I am building a blog in both English and Spanish languages. My intention is to access the default content, in Spanish, directly from the base url: `http://blog/` and the English content from `http://blog/en`.

I already have all the code to loop through posts only in English or Spanish when paginating by checking the `locale` variable that I set in every post front matter. Although my blog posts don't have the same filename, I link them using another variable in the front matter called `ref`.

So for post A, in Spanish, and post B, in English, I'll have something like this:

2018-01-01-post-A.md

```
---
locale: en
ref: my-ref
---
foo
```

2019-01-04-post-B.md:

```
---
locale: es
ref: my-ref
---
bar
```

My question is: where do I put my English posts so that they can be accessed through `http://blog/en/post-name/`?

Those posts already have their categories apart from their language, so putting them inside `/en/_posts` wouldn't work, as when specifying the permalink in `_config.yml` to something like `permalink: /:categories/:year/:month/:title/` would make the url look like `http://blog/en/category-1/category-2/post-name`.

Defining a permalink in each English post is also not an option, since I'd like them to be generated from the post data (date and title).

Is there something that I'm missing that would let me use `/en/` as part of the URL as I want?

Both the menu language selector and the pagination work, displaying only posts in the selected language. However, when hovering over the posts in english, although I put them inside `_posts/en`, the subfolder doesn't become part of the url. The same happens when I try the opposite, creating a new folder in the project root named `en` and adding all the English posts inside it, leaving me with something like `en/_posts/`

Comment: This should help you: https://github.com/Anthony-Gaudino/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin

Comment: Not really. My question is not related to which plugin could help me. I want to know how to propagate a subdirectory of posts as part of the blog's URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set a [frontmatter default](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/front-matter-defaults/) for your english pages.

```
# _config.yml

defaults:
-
    scope:
      locale: "en" # To sort by locale. You could also sort by path.
      type: "posts"
    values:
      permalink: en/:categories/:year/:month/:title/
```

Comment: This did the trick! Is there any downside to this approach? I assume I'll have to create another default for type: "pages" and duplicate all of them, right?

Comment: It's worth reading the docs I linked. Anything you can set by frontmatter, you can set a default value for. No downsides, this is exactly the sort of thing it was made for!

Comment: Thanks Robert! Accepting your solution.